# Vue component is reactive only with specific name

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I am experiencing one bizare problem with which you will probably not be able to help me, but I will try asking it anyway:

My Vue component does not want to update when it has specific name. When I rename it, it updates without problem.

To be precise, I named my Vue component `Webinar.vue`.
Here is the code for "Webinar.vue":

```html
<template><div>test</div></template>
```

I display this component in browser in my Web application and it displays properly.
Now, I change `test` to `test2` and save file and nothing happens.

But if I change the name of the component to be, for example, `Webi.vue` and do not change any content of the file nor anything anywhere else in the project, no config, nothing, it starts working. When I write `test` inside the `div` browser displays `test`, when I set `test1` it displays `test1` and so on.

When I change the name of the component back to the original name, update stops working again. And this is not the only name that does not work. I found a few other names that do not work, one of which is `Webin`.

How is this possible?

I know that you probably will not be able to help me since I did not provide minimal reproducable example, and if you ask me about the project, about the environment where is this running, I would say "it is complicated", so yea... But if one name works, just by changing the component name it should not stop working, right?

This is very bizare bug. I have very interesting environment... This component is nested within another component, that component is initialized from within the JSP file, there is Vue object created, JSP is rendered by Liferay, there is node.js involved, webpack and so on and so on. Very complex project with a lot of unusual stuff. Only way I can get this component to refresh when it has "bad name", is by restarting the node completely.
Vue in question is Vue 2.

But, how can changing the name of the component unbreak it. I do not get that.

Comment: Maybe caching.
I have to a) restart a page or b) restart the dev server (webpack) for some changes to work properly, try that

Comment: " Only way I can get this component to refresh when it has "bad name", is by restarting the node completely" - this totally depends on your setup, which is unknown

Comment: @Dimava, yes, when I restart the node server, or webpack, changes do apply. But when I make changes again, they do not apply until node is restarted again. I checked browser caching, I emptied it, tried in anonymous window but the same behaviour happens every time.

Comment: It is poor form to name Vue components using only one word. Naming conventions dictate they must be PascalCase or kebob-cased. Try renaming your component to ‘TheWebinar.vue’